# csv data into python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I got a quite a large csv file with data and I want to take the data (just a bunch of floating numbers) from a row and turn it into a list. Preferably without using a for-loop because there is quite a lot of data.

The file looks like this (+600 columns):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD3dr.png)

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('BM1-2022-Gruppe_18_stål_8mm.csv')

print(data)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1083, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1233, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1246, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1444, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 16: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\terje\Desktop\test (2).py", line 3, in 
data = pd.read_csv('BM1-2022-Gruppe_18_stål_8mm.csv')
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 950, in read_csv
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 611, in _read
return parser.read(nrows)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1772, in read
) = self._engine.read(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 243, in read
chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 808, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1037, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1090, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1233, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1246, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1444, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 16: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: You can use pandas.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name')

Comment: So you want to take data from all 600 cols, and convert it into 1 list i.e [float from col1, float from col2,...float from col600] for all rows?